# Float binary (0.11001100) to decimal number. BY HAND

Tags: floating-point, binary, decimal

Can not find information about this

I think it can be done by `(0*2^0)+(0*2^-1)+(1*2^-2)+(1*2^-3)+(0*2^-4)+(0*2^-5)+(1*2^-6)+(1*2^-7)`.
But I need some help to understand if it's true or not. Or maybe it's in the opposite direction

Answer (score 2):

Opposite. And start with 2<sup>0</sup> in front of the point:

0·2<sup>0</sup>+1·2<sup>-1</sup>+1·2<sup>-2</sup>+0·2<sup>-3</sup>+0·2<sup>-4</sup>+1·2<sup>-5</sup>+1·2<sup>-6</sup>+0·2<sup>-7</sup>+0·2<sup>-8</sup>